# How to get fontforge module to print waterfall samples?

Tags: python, fontforge

I am writing a Python script to go through my font collection (some TTF, some OFD, some SFD) and eventually make a single document (PDF?) with sample pages for all of them.

My desired output format would be similar to what you get when you view a font file in Windows or Gnome; a sample is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuAov.png) from qubodup's answer in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5715/how-to-view-a-ttf-font-file). Using that answer, I can use ImageMagick to generate sample images for TTF and OFD files.

I am trying to using fontforge to handle the SFD files. I am on ubuntu, have installed fontforge and python-fontforge. I am using https://fontforge.github.io/python.html for documentation, specifically the sections on printSetup and printSample.

This script works fine for printing the fontdisplay and fontsample, but the waterfall comes up with just the header "Sample Sizes of FX Matrix 105 Mono Compr Exp Dbl UL Sub Italic" and no waterfall text. I have fiddled with the pointsize tuple on the printSample call (including not using a tuple), and a variety of values for the printSample 3rd parameter.

```
import fontforge

amb = fontforge.open('FXMatrix105MonoComprExpDblULSubItalic.sfd')
fontforge.printSetup('pdf-file', 'z.pdf')
amb.printSample('fontdisplay', 24, 'abcdefABCDEF', 'fontdisplay.pdf')
amb.printSample('waterfall', (12, 16, 24, 36), 'abcdefABCDEF', 'waterfall.pdf')
amb.printSample('fontsample', 24, 'abcdefABCDEF', 'fontsample.pdf')
```

I would expect the `printSample('waterfall', ...)` to give me a sample of the font at a variety of point sizes (like when you view a font file in Windows or Linux), but like I wrote, waterfall.pdf just has the header "Sample Sizes of FX Matrix 105 Mono Compr Exp Dbl UL Sub Italic" and nothing underneath that.

What am I doing wrong with my attempt to do a waterfall document from the fontforge python module?

Comment: I put this in as an issue on the font-forge project in Github. Here is the resolution (at https://github.com/fontforge/fontforge/issues/3457)

Answer (score 1):

I posted this as an issue on the fontforge project on github; I was not providing enough information (and didn't understand what a waterfall page is)

Thanks for [Fredrick Brennan ctrlcctrlv](https://github.com/ctrlcctrlv), answer at https://github.com/fontforge/fontforge/issues/3457:

> The reason this is happening is you haven't selected the letters
>   first. Try:
>
> ````
> fontforge.open('FXMatrix105MonoComprExpDblULSubItalic.sfd')
> fontforge.printSetup('pdf-file', 'z.pdf')
> amb.selection.select(("unicode","ranges"),ord('A'),ord('Z'))
> amb.printSample('waterfall', (12, 16, 24, 36), 'abcdefABCDEF',
> 'waterfall.pdf') ```
> ````